# How to make calculation inside django annotate?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This one when I run generates error:

```
qs = UserLocation.objects.annotate(distance=0.5 - cos((F('lat')-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p) * cos(F('lat')*p) * (1-cos((F('long')-lon1)*p))/2).all()
```

The error it generates is this one:

> must be real number, not CombinedExpression

How can I make that calculation as an annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding ExpressionWrapper as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

```
qs = UserLocation.objects.annotate(distance=ExpressionWrapper(0.5 - cos((F('lat')-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p) * cos(F('lat')*p) * (1-cos((F('long')-lon1)*p))/2).all(), output_field=FloatField())
```

I might missed some `)` because your calculation is complicated and I assumed that result is a float

Comment: This is the correct answer, is there any way I can annotate that distance using a function (just for code readability). ps. I know I cannot pass the `F('lat') or F('long')` as parameters to a function as that is done in DB, but I was thinking if there is any way. By this I mean calling like `get_distance()` instead of that long line

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [Django's Cos database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#cos) when finding the cosine of a value which involves an `F()` expression.

Python's `math.cos` function seems to produce the **must be real number** error when used with an `F()` expression.

To take a simple example, this produces the **must be real number** error:

```
from math import cos

...

Vector.objects.annotate(x_cos=cos(F('x') + 1))
```

But this seems to work:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cos

...

Vector.objects.annotate(x_cos=Cos(F('x') + 1))
```

So to take your example, I think you'll want something like this:

```
from math import cos
from django.db.models.functions import Cos

...

qs = UserLocation.objects.annotate(distance=0.5 - Cos((F('lat')-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p) * Cos(F('lat')*p) * (1-Cos((F('long')-lon1)*p))/2)
```